# google maps v3 - setting icon dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Can anyone tell me why the following is not working please?

Everything works with this apart from the iconType

```
 function createMarker(map, position, number, title, iconType) {
      var flag = 'http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/images/beachflag.png';
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        icon: iconType,
        map: map
      });
```

If i set 'icon' directly to the variable 'flag' it works, but when i pull it in from the function variable 'iconType' it does not?

I have tested to make sure that the variable 'flag' is passed to this function.

You can see the whole code here: http://www.oroojo.co.uk/ed/gmaps-2.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're setting the `icon` property to the string `"flag"`, not pointing it to a variable `flag`.